# ffmpeg libplacebo filter cropping doesn't work

Tags: ffmpeg

Cropping a video using `libplacebo` filter doesn't work as expected. I want to crop and scale a video, I am using the following filter:

```
-vf libplacebo=crop_x=0:crop_y=138:crop_w=1920:crop_h=804:w=1280:h=-2: \
               force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:normalize_sar=true
```

**Expected behavior:** video is cropped from 1920x1080 to 1920x804, and then scaled to the width of 1280 with height determined automatically preserving the aspect ratio, which would result in a 1280x536 video.

**My result:** video is cropped, but then forcefully stretched to 1280x720, not preserving the aspect ratio.

It works when I am using ffmpeg's standard `crop` and then passing the cropped video to `libplacebo` filter:

```
-vf crop=1920:804:0:138,libplacebo=w=1280:h=-2:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:normalize_sar=true
```

But I'd like to understand how to crop using `libplacebo` native means and replicate the default `crop` behavior.

It works as expected using `ffplay`:

```
ffplay -vf "libplacebo=crop_x=0:crop_y=138:crop_w=1920:crop_h=804:w=1920:h=804" input.mkv
```

I am getting a properly cropped 1920x804 video that is not stretched to 1920x1080, with the correct aspect ratio. But I can't seem to get it working when trying to encode it into a new file with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: What's your full command?

Comment: @Gyan ```ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "libplacebo=crop_x=0:crop_y=138:crop_w=1920:crop_h=804:w=1280:h=-2:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:normalize_sar=true" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv```
ffmpeg version: ```ffmpeg version 2023-06-19-git-1617d1a752-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers```

Answer (score 0):

Change `h=-2` to `h=ow/(a*sar)`, `normalize_sar` to `false`.

And add `setsar=1` filter after libplacebo.

Comment: Didn't work.
Here is the source video: https://i.imgur.com/DcRxEHy.png
And here is the cropped and scaled video: https://i.imgur.com/2VL77Yh.png
Yet again, it forcefully stretches it to the height of 720px and messes up the aspect ratio, when all I want to do is crop black borders and preserve the aspect ratio with ```libplacebo``` crop.
```ffmpeg -hide_banner -i .\input.mkv -init_hw_device vulkan -vf "libplacebo=crop_x=0:crop_y=138:crop_w=1920:crop_h=804:w=1280:h=ow/(a*sar):force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:normalize_sar=false,setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv```

Comment: Okay, I've experimented a bit. It worked like this:

```ffmpeg -hide_banner -i test.mkv -init_hw_device vulkan -vf "libplacebo=crop_x=0:crop_y=138:crop_w=1920:crop_h=804:w=1920:h=804,libplacebo=w=1280:h=-2:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:normalize_sar=false,setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 output.mkv```

But it's really rather cumbersome and I am not sure if it's any better than just using the default `crop` first, and then `libplacebo` to scale.

Comment: Sorry, remove `force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease` and then use my changes.

Comment: FTR, the SAR logic was recently changed/updated, see https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/5fdb12d6a06016ee01022b96f271b7223976c3d8